# PHP array object unexplained behavor

Tags: php, object, var-dump

I simply cannot find an explanation for this bizarre behavior:

Given the following array:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(Craft\DateTime)[225]
      public 'date' => string '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
  1 => 
    object(Craft\DateTime)[231]
      public 'date' => string '2017-02-02 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

If I do the following:

```
foreach($myArray as $data){
     var_dump($data->date);
}
```

The result of the var_dump is NULL. Not only is that incorrect but if before the foreach I add the following:

```
var_dump($test);
```

I then get output. So how could a `var_dump` possibly have any bearing on the value of itself. It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `var_dump` actually does add the `date` property. It does seems strange when you first encounter it.

Comment: I encountered something similar when I asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487774/what-are-these-undocumented-properties-in-dateinterval

Comment: Seriously thought I was losing the plot!

Comment: `echo $data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`  inside foreach. check once. Rest Don't Panic is correct

Comment: DateTime object properties can't be directly accessed from within code, but are still visible for var_dump(), etc. This is a known [b̶u̶g̶  feature](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49382)